# Motion in a straight line?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

I am trying to solve the following problem that involves motion in a straight line. I am not quite sure how to go about it though. I know it will involve formulas and derivatives but which specific ones would I use?

> An electron has a constant acceleration of 2.6 m/s^2. At a certain
>   instant its velocity is 12.1 m/s.
>
> What was its velocity 2.5 s earlier?  What was its velocity 2.5 s
>   later?

Comment: For *constant acceleration*, $\Delta v = a \Delta t$.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the particle being an electron is a catch, standard equations of motion can be used.
$v= u + at$ with symbols having usual meanings.
for 2.5 sec earlier:
$v = 12.1 \mathrm{\ m/s}$,  $a = 2.6 \mathrm{\ m/s^2}$,
$u = ?$,        $t = 2.5 \mathrm{\ s}$

Similarly for 2.5 sec later
$v = ?$,        $a = 2.6 \mathrm{\ m/s}^2$,
$u = 12.1\mathrm{\ m/s}$,  $t = 2.5 \mathrm{\ s}$.